# Translating Natural Language to LTL Formulae

Tags: logic, linear-temporal-logic

I'm brand new to LTL and working on becoming better with LTL formulae. I've got two examples where I am unsure whether my LTL formula is correct.

I'm given the sentences, and my assumption is that $l$ is true:

1. $l$ is always false after $m$

LTL Translation: $G(m \to  G(\neg l))$ i.e on all paths m implies on all paths not l

2. $l$ is false between $m$ and $n$

LTL Translation: $G((m \land Fn) \to \neg l \space Un)$ i.e on all paths m and finally n, implies not l until n

Is my thinking correct in the examples? Thanks for the help!

Comment: $G$ had better be translated as on all *subsequent* path. For 1. isn't p a typo and should be $l$? And its translation seems very straightforward. For 2. again  isn't p a typo and should be $l$? And $F$ had better be translated as "eventually somewhere on the subsequent path". Overall sounds fine to me.

Comment: @mohottnad yes p is a mistype. Sorry about this. Thanks for reviewing!

Comment: @mohottnad I am thinking my last formula is wrong because it's not 'always' that $l$ is false between $m$ and $n$. Would it be $(m \land Fn) \to \neg l \space Un$? I just removed the G.

Comment: But your spec requirement of 2 clearly states "$l$ is false between $m$ and $n$", I don't understand why it's not always so? Your goal is to write such a sentence to satisfy the spec, right? In general in LTL we need unary or binary operators for the whole sentence.

Comment: @mohottnad I was just wondering if there would a difference in the LTL formula for "$l$ is ALWAYS false between $m$ and $n$" and "$l$ is false between $m$ and $n$".

Comment: If you use $U$ as above then $l$ must be always false between $m$ and $n$. If you interpret your spec as $l$ only needs sometimes false between $m$ and $n$, then you may try something like $G((m∧F(¬l))→ Fn)$...

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Answer (score 0):

There is a kind of templates to translate common NLP patterns into LTL.
https://matthewbdwyer.github.io/psp/patterns/ltl.html

Hope it helps :D.